# How to run node main.js startup command on windows azure app service from post deployment action in azure release pipeline?

Tags: node.js, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines, nestjs

I have windows azure app service and azure CI/CD pipeline to automate the deployment of nestjs app.
From CI pipeline I'm only copying package.json, .env and main executable file by webpack on app service.. So in CD pipeline I push these these 3 files on azure app service and run app from post deployment scripts which is working fine like node modules are installed as well but the azure app gives 502.
Can someone confirm that is it the right way to run node main.js in post deployment script in azure release pipeline.

- below is my post deployment action script

  1- cd /home/site/wwwroot/apps/workflows
  2- npm install --only=prod --ignore-scripts
  3- node main.js
  [image]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of keeping node main.js script in Post Deployment Action you can add the script in app service Start command itself in **package.json** file.

If you want to start your App Service in a startup command, you can follow the below process to achieve

**Note:** The Post Deployment Action is used to alter the contents of deployment after deployment is successful.

By default, Azure App Service check for start command in `package.json` file. In your **`package.json`** file add your startup script in Scripts portion **`"start": "node main.js"`**

```json
{
"name": "node-js",
"version": "0.2.0",
"description": "A sample Node.js app using Express 4",
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
// here you can mention your start script
    "start": "node main.js"
},
...
```

Refer [MS-DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-nodejs?pivots=platform-linux#run-with-pm2) for NodeJS to start script.